# What do you call rubbery objects with long rubbery blades?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I think I've seen something similar to those monkey rings, but in cleaning products, but I don't remember what products they were exactly. What do you call those?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Food spatula? Food scraper? Toilet bowl brush?